# Keyboard and mouse stop working

Tags: windows-7

I have computer. I used it for 6 month without having problem. But now i have problem on keyboard and mouse. Every time turn on the computer it work correctly for 2 or 3 minutes. After that it stop responding. First I thought it have problem with OS. Then I installed windows. But now also it happen as before. When it happen I change the port that mouse and keyboard are connected. Then it again work for 2 or 3 minutes and stop working. I check whether the port I used before can used for other devices so I insert USB flash drive. It detected. So I am confuse what the real problem is. I hope will get your help soon.

Thanks.

Comment: Did You tried diffrent devices?

Comment: I have never tried the different

Comment: I second Adam's suggestion I would also check power property on the USB

Answer (score 1):

When I had this problem of the mouse and keyboard suddenly going dead I noticed a **brs.exe** process in my task manager that I didn't remember ever seeing before.

It has something to do with playing DVDs apparently, but is not essential, according to what I read, so I prevented it from loading at start up.

It's only been about a day and a half, but I've left my computer on continually and have not had a freeze since I stopped brs.exe from running.  My keyboard and mouse had been freezing every hour or two for the couple of days before that, so I'm hoping that file may have been causing my problem.

The removal of brs.exe only worked for about a day, and then the same problem was back. So probably brs.exe wasn't the problem. Since then I've uninstalled all Adobe products, and disabled the Dell Backup as per http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/149635-safely-disable-stserviceexe-process-in-windows-7/ but I'm still getting the keyboard and mouse freezing up, so that I have to pull the plug.